# no output for java client/server app

Tags: java, chat

thank u for all ur previous responses which are very helpful. 
I have another Q for server/client app. I gt the connection between server/client.
But now when I type something, nothing happens. The run() that I implement listens to input and display them. It seems that this method is not working (thats why there no output I guess)

This is the run() (listen and display message received) and the send() (send message)

Thank you

```
public void run(){//watch for incoming communication
        String msg;

        try{//loop reading lines from the client and display msg
            while ((msg = serverIn.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("msg received"+msg);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }   
    }

    public void send(String msg){//send outgoing message
        System.out.println("in the send()");
        serverOut.println(msg);
    }
```

Some information that could be helpful:
Those method is in class I call them by

```
someClass.start() (someClass extends Thread class)
someClass.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to flush the output stream.

```
  public void send(String msg){//send outgoing message
        System.out.println("in the send()");
        serverOut.println(msg);
serverOut.flush();
    }
```

That's assuming whatever `serverOut` is a `PrintWriter` which it seems to be?

Comment: yes, its a prinwriter. Btw, Are input/output stream of server different from input/output stream of client? Thank you

Comment: @kaboom what exactly do you mean by different?

Comment: the tutorial that I read make it sound like input/output stream of server and client are different. So u have 1 printWriter for server output stream, and then u have to have another printWriter for client output stream? thanks a lot

Comment: @kaboom Well they aren't even controlled by the same program most likely.. so yes you'd have to create something to write with both of the server and client.